# How to get reference on annotation via sender?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mkmapview

I connect annotation with UITapGestureRecognizer.
I  want to detect touch.

```
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
 {
     NSString * annotationIdentifier = @"UserAnnotationIdentifier";
     CustomAnnotationView * customAnnotationView = (CustomAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
     if (!customAnnotationView)
     {
         customAnnotationView = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
         UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
         [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 action:@selector(calloutTapped:)];
         [customAnnotationView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

I use the code bottom, but it caused error in compilation

```
  -(void) calloutTapped:(id) sender {
       id<MKAnnotation> annotation = ((MKAnnotationView*)sender.view).annotation;
```

ERROR: property view not found on object of type __strong id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
-(void) calloutTapped:(id) sender
```

to:

```
-(void) calloutTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
```

then the `sender` would have the `view` property
**or** first cast the `sender` to `UITapGestureRecognizer`.
To cast correctly:

```
 -(void) calloutTapped:(id) sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    MKAnnotationView *sendersView = (MKAnnotationView *)tapGesture.view;
    id<MKAnnotation> annotation = sendersView.annotation;
}
```

Comment: thanks, you make my day! I accept answer a bit later

Comment: How can I cast the sender to UITapGestureRecognizer?  sender = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender; not works

Comment: I updated my answer with casting on each item. It's correct to set the `tag` properties of your annotation views so you can identify them and  reuse this method for multiple tap gestures. just a thought.